How to set referrer or origin for requests within iframe
Given is my webpage called www.example.com that loads an iframe from subdomain.example.com. I control the www page, the subdomain and the nginx server that serves the content.
For Cloudflare, I want to cache all resources ONLY WHEN subdomain.example.com is requested from within the iframe. If the users directly visits subdomain.example.com I don't want to apply this caching rule.
In order to do that, I need to pass information in the HTTP Header Request for the subdomain. I believe that many mechanisms are involved here, from a referrer policy, origins, and Content Security Policy.
When a resource for the subdomain is loaded within the iframe, can I send information that this request is indirectly made from www.example.com? Would that URL be set in Origin or Referrer?
What header information would my Nginx instance need to provide for the subdomain, and what headers for the main page?
Thanks a lot!
TLDR
How do I make a browser set the referrer to the URL of the parent page when that parent page loads an iframe
